# List folders and files in a UNC root folder

Tags: powershell, directory, subdirectory, unc

I am trying to get folders and files from the root of a UNC path name. I am using `Get-ChildItem`.

I can get results from a subfolder via the UNC path, but not the root folder. If run the command `Get-ChildItem \\sf1\user1` from the command line, results are returned.

```
    Directory: \\sf1\user1


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        11/14/2013   3:40 PM            1.ISGROUP
```

When I try to execute `Get-ChildItem \\sf1` from the command line I get errors.

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\sf1' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem \\sf1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\sf1:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Any suggestions on how to get folders and files from the root of a UNC path?

Comment: `\\sf1` is not a valid UNC path

Comment: The question reveals a lack of understanding of how UNC paths and the Windows network redirector works. As @MathiasR.Jessen says, a server name by itself is not in itself a valid UNC path.

Comment: you can view the shares like this `net view sf1`

Answer (score 5):

As Mathias pointed out, a valid UNC path consists of at least server and share (`\\servername\sharename`), optionally subfolders too (`\\servername\sharename\sub\folder`). You cannot list files/folders directly from a server. If you want to enumerate shares on the remote server use `net view \\servername` (as Anthony Stringer mentioned). Note that this will list only visible shares. If you also want to list hidden shares (shares whose name ends with a `$`) you need to run `net share` on the server

```
Invoke-Command -Computer servername -ScriptBlock { & net share }
```

or use WMI

```
Get-WmiObject -Computer servername -Class Win32_Share
```