# PowerShell Test-Path UNC with a wildcard

Tags: powershell, wildcard, unc

I'm trying to test if a UNC path exists, but all attempts have failed so far.
This folder example exists, and returns true:

> ```
> \\Server\Path1
> ```

I'd like to confirm all folders with similar names exist, such as:

> ```
> \\Server\Path2 
> \\Server\Path3 etc.
> ```

I've tried using a wildcard in these examples:

```
test-path "\\Server\Path*"
resolve-path "\\Server\Path*"
[System.IO.Directory]::Exists('\\Server\Path*');
Test-Path $('filesystem::\\Server\Path*')
```

...Along with many permutations of the \ " ' * combination. 
However, nothing I've tried returns a 'True' for this type of path when using a wildcard, even though it seems to work fine for: `Test-Path c:\windows\system3*` for example.

Comment: Your Path has to be `\\Server\C$\Path*`

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35068220/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Windows supports wildcard selection on share names.

But if you have sufficient (remote) access to the file server you can get a list of shares:

```
Get-WmiObject -class 'Win32_Share' -ComputerName 'Server'
```

Comment: That's answered the question, thanks very much. 
For completeness, this is the line I've used to discern the existence of 'Pathx':
    `Get-WmiObject -class 'Win32_Share' -ComputerName 'Server' | where Name -Like "*Path*"`

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will work for mapped UNC paths :

```
   Get-PSDrive| where{$_.DisplayRoot -like "\\server\test*" } | foreach{test-path -path $_.DisplayRoot}
```

If you have wmi access ,then :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName server | where{$_.name -like "test*"} | foreach{Test-Path "\\server\$($_.name)"}
```